# Differences between HTML/CSS settings and Javascript Settings - Mainly Svg>Line elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a minor problem I cannot seem to solve. I have created a table, each cell has a svg>line element within it. The differences are, 1 line has them manually added, and the other through a loop in Javascript. The problem is that the ones in Javascript are not shown, even tho they are the same.

Manually Added:

```
<table id="centertable" class="table">
    <tr class="celldates" id="topDate"></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <svg>
                <line x1="0" y1="50%" x2="100%" y2="50%"/>
            </svg>
        </td>
        <td>
            <svg>
                <line x1="20%" y1="50%" x2="60%" y2="50%"/>
            </svg>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Added through Javascript:

```
function setPersonTimes(person, weeks){
    for(let i = 0; i < person; i++){
        var a = document.createElement("tr");
        var b = document.createElement("td");
        b.classList.add("tableLeftContent");
        b.innerHTML = "Person"
        a.appendChild(b);
        document.getElementById("lefttable").appendChild(a);
        var c = document.createElement("tr");
        c.classList.add("celldata");
        for(let i2 = 0; i2 < weeks*7; i2++){
            var d = document.createElement("td");
            var e = document.createElement("svg");
            var f = document.createElement("line");
            f.setAttribute("x1", "0%")
            f.setAttribute("y1", "50%")
            f.setAttribute("x2", "80%")
            f.setAttribute("y2","50%")
            d.appendChild(e);
            e.appendChild(f);
            c.appendChild(d);
        }
        document.getElementById("centertable").appendChild(c);
    }
```

}

Now the problem as mentioned, is that the lines that are added with Javascript, are not visible, even tho they are added.
They are visibly shown as the following:

[image: Example]

The green ones are manually added and uses the CSS code:

```
   svg{
        height: 10px;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        stroke-width: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        stroke: green;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgb(0, 0, 0);
        float:left;
    }
```

Any ideas why it does show when adding it manually, but not via Javascript?

Comment: In Javascript you try to append the rows to a table whose ID is "lefttable" (`document.getElementById("lefttable").appendChild(a);`) but in the HTML code your table has the ID "centertable" (`<table id="centertable" class="table">`).

Comment: The whole example is a little bit messed up. Where does `lefttable` come from? Why in the JS generated code you add a `celldata` class to the row with the svg tags but not in the manually added one? The code is also missing the row with class `celldates`

Comment: Also, what are the data types of `person` and `weeks`? You are using them as if they were numbers (e.g. `for(let i = 0; i < person; i++)` and `for(let i2 = 0; i2 < weeks*7; i2++)`); is that correct? Where and how is `setPersonTimes()` called?

Comment: @secan person is just a integer with x amount of persons. They are whats shown in the image-example as Person on the left. Weeks are just the amount of weeks listed as vertical columns, each week has 7days, hence the multiplication of 7. So yes, you are correct. They are simply numbers. SetPersonTimes() is simple called at the beginning of the <script> section with 2 numerical arguments.

Comment: @Enak I did not bring the whole set of code as I only brought what's directly relevant to what I am asking. But to answer your question, some cells will not be used and I specify them using these classes/IDs so they won't be affected by the general CSS rules that should apply to the majority of the cells. I by purposely have added these so they don't need to be within the script. Left table class is what you see as the table on the left, with Person tags. But again, these are not directly related to the question of vector visibility within the central cells.

Comment: By the way, you do not need to use a SVG image to render a "progress bar"; two DIVs properly styled can do the same and might be easier to manage. You can see an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/0yuserkh/1/

Comment: @secan Had not thought of that... I mainly wanted vectors as they can be positioned easily. Technically it is a time period within within a specific time interval, which can vary. You can see on the second green line that it is neither at the starting point nor the endpoint, but something in the middle. And using vector % positioning within a cell allows me to have a flexible platform regardless of screen/client/instance size. But thanks for the example, I will take a closer look later.

Comment: You can do the same with DIVs, using `margin-left` (https://jsfiddle.net/exj40owp/) ;)

Comment: It seems the response from ibrahim did not work, however I am going to continue working with a better solution that @secan came up with. I just have to tweak some formulas to it as it creates it differently, but it is a much simpler solution, which I am a fan off. :-) So thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using `document.createElement("svg")`, however the the HTML parser has no hint about the namespace of this element. Therefore it will get assigned to default `xhtml` namespace of `"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`

You need to use

```js
document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg")
```

see the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElementNS)

Comment: Ah, that might be it. I removed that to begin with and then forgotten about it. I will try it out when I am at my desk later. Thank you!